# Increasing Rows per Page in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I'm looking for a way to increase the number of rows per page in an SSRS report beyond 50.  There are dozens upon dozens of guides on changing the rows per page via a parent group that breaks based on a *CEILING(RowNumber(Nothing)/X)* calculation, but every guide I've come across seems to be focused on decreasing the rows per page, and I want to increase the rows per page.

If I try a number higher than 50 for my breaks--CEILING(RowNumber(Nothing)/100), for example--it still caps the rows per page at 50.  Using a number below 50 does work.  Is there a report setting I've missed somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No matter where you set pages breaks, if the content exceeds the page size then the page will break. I'm assuming that you are viewing on screen only in which case you need to increase the height of the report's `interactive size` property.

Comment: Agreedo: you have to literally shrink the size of the content. Reduce the font size as much as possible, set the top and bottom padding in all cells to zero, and reduce the row height to accommodate.

Answer (score 3):

A bit late, but today I was trying to do this same thing.

I managed to do it by going to **Report Properties -> Page Setup** and increase the **Height** property.

**Report Properties** can be opened by right clicking in the blank space outside the report working area.

Depending on the Height will be the number of elements in the page, in my case I was able to show 100 rows per page with a Height of 21.5in

Comment: As a relatively new SSRS user, I was struggling to find the Report Properties. Thank you for the explicit directions. It is IMO less than intuitively obvious, so this was a huge help!